# xml namespace appears xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm making an application that extracts YouTube data, and I've run into a few problems.

I have this code:

```
        XDocument docAuthor = XDocument.Parse(XDocument.Load("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/crashcourse/uploads?v=2&alt=atom&max-results=0").ToString());
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

        XElement entryAuthor = docAuthor.Root.Element(ns + "author");
        txbxConsole.Text = entryAuthor.Element(ns + "name").ToString();
```

This is the output: `<name xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">crashcourse</name>`

But I want it to be: `crashcourse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the element to `string`

```
txbxConsole.Text = (string)entryAuthor.Element(ns + "name");
```

Or you can also use `.Value` property. `XElement.ToString` returns the entire element, not just the value.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Selman's answer, you can just retrieve the value of the node:

```
txbxConsole.Text = entryAuthor.Element(ns + "name").Value;
```